# Is there a way to directly read data in an Excel attachment received in an email in Microsoft Power Automate?

Tags: excel, power-automate

I have created a MS Flow which triggers as soon as an email with attachment comes into the inbox folder, now this part I am able to achieve it and also i am able to add action to get attachment successfully from the email.

What I want to achieve or know is?

Now I want to read the data inside the received attachment directly in the MS flow without storing it any location of any sort, reading the data inside the attachment directly from the email.

Is it possible or this is a wrong expectation and we have to store it in share point or one drive or any other location to read the data inside the excel attachment received in the email?

IF this is possible to read data inside attachment received along with email directly from MS flow, can you please let me know step by step how to do it as fairly new to the flow?

Searched blogs did not find anything related to the query I have.

Comment: The way which I have used is to store it in onedrive or sharepoint and read it from there. Sorry I dont think reading attachment without storing is possible.

Comment: May be you can try  this approach. If you do not want to waste storage space. Once you read your document from online storage, trigger action to delete the file which you have stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to directly read the attachment from email in Power Automate or a logic app. We have to store it somewhere then only we can read it.